# Creating terminal window in web page using php

Tags: php, cmd, terminal, exec

I want to create a web page like a linux terminal and can access terminal from web page. Can anyone tell me solution or some ideas. (in PHP)

Comment: I already read that... I need more than that :)

Comment: What more could you possibly want than executing all the linux commands?

Comment: I want linux terminal on my browser(visually)

Comment: I agree with this. Someone please answer!